# Showing Google Admob Interstitial ad in Xamarin Forms without delay

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on Xamarin forms project and i have implemented Interstitial ad on all three platforms (Google admob doesn't support UWP). Ads are working fine but they are showing with a delay of 4 to 5 seconds. All i want is to finish that delay so they can show immediately.

PCL class.

```
public interface IAdmobInterstitial
{
    void Show(string adUnit);
}
```

Droid Code.

```
public class InterstitialAdListener : AdListener
{
    readonly InterstitialAd _ad;

    public InterstitialAdListener(InterstitialAd ad)
    {
        _ad = ad;
    }

    public override void OnAdLoaded()
    {
        base.OnAdLoaded();

        if (_ad.IsLoaded)
            _ad.Show();
    }
}

public class AdmobInterstitial : Controls.IAdmobInterstitial
{
    InterstitialAd _ad;

    public void Show(string adUnit)
    {
        var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        _ad = new InterstitialAd(context);
        _ad.AdUnitId = adUnit;

        var intlistener = new InterstitialAdListener(_ad);
        intlistener.OnAdLoaded();
        _ad.AdListener = intlistener;

        var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("302E90D530B2193F59FDD7F22A11B45A");
        _ad.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
    }
}
```

iOS Code.

```
public class AdmobInterstitial : IAdmobInterstitial
{
    Interstitial _adInterstitial;

    public void Show(string adUnit)
    {
        _adInterstitial = new Interstitial(adUnit);
        var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
        _adInterstitial.AdReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (_adInterstitial.IsReady)
            {
                var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
                var vc = window.RootViewController;
                while (vc.PresentedViewController != null)
                {
                    vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
                }
                _adInterstitial.PresentFromRootViewController(vc);
            }
        };
        _adInterstitial.LoadRequest(request);

    }
}
```

Calling interstitial ad on PCL page.

```
DependencyService.Get<IAdmobInterstitial>().Show("(id will come here)");
Navigation.PushAsync(new Page());
```

Ad is showing perfectly but with a delay. I want to show the ad first and then the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i just solved this.
Here is the code.

PCL Class. Add another function to your interface.

```
public interface IAdmobInterstitial
{
    void Show(string adUnit);

    void Give();
}
```

Droid code. Put _ad.Show() in the new function.

```
public class InterstitialAdListener : AdListener
{
    readonly InterstitialAd _ad;

    public InterstitialAdListener(InterstitialAd ad)
    {
        _ad = ad;
    }

    public override void OnAdLoaded()
    {
        base.OnAdLoaded();

        //if (_ad.IsLoaded)
        //    _ad.Show();
    }
}

public class AdmobInterstitial : Controls.IAdmobInterstitial
{
    InterstitialAd _ad;

    public void Show(string adUnit)
    {
        var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        _ad = new InterstitialAd(context);
        _ad.AdUnitId = adUnit;

        var intlistener = new InterstitialAdListener(_ad);
        intlistener.OnAdLoaded();
        _ad.AdListener = intlistener;

        var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("302E90D530B2193F59FDD7F22A11B45A");
        _ad.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
    }

    public void Give()
    {
        if (_ad.IsLoaded)
            _ad.Show();
    }
}
```

Now, call the function Show() in the constructor of your MainPage in PCL and call the function Give() when you press the button for the next page.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DependencyService.Get<IAdmobInterstitial>().Show("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    }

private void button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IAdmobInterstitial>().Give();
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Percentage());
    }
```

This is only for Android. Same goes for iOS as well.

I hope it helps the other programmers. :)